# Qubit-deliver action in console

Tags: javascript, console

I'm hoping I have this information correct but virtually i am using firebug console to view a GET request and want to use the command line to view that the action of the GET request is "qubit-deliver'. When I type in 'Universal_variable_event', it comes up with an reference error. Have I got this command wrong? How can I call a command on a specific GET request to see the action?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

With the old Universal Variable object, you can see the events being sent in the console by using `universal_variable.events`. With the new QProtocol standard, you'd need to look in the `uv.events` array - both these arrays contain events that have been sent on the current pageview and will correspond with network requests to Qubit's REST API.